# How to retain grep color when storing in variable or piping to another command?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm wanting to use the `grep` in a bash script to find matching lines in a file, highlight the matches with color, and then print out the results in a table using the `column` command. Something like this:

```
data=`cat file.data | egrep -i --color "$search"`
echo $'\n'"col1"$'\t'"col2"$'\t'"col3"$'\t'"col4"$'\n'"$data" | column -t -s$'\t'
```

The above code does everything as desired, *except* that the color is lost.

---

Here's a simplified example:

[image]

As you can see, when I used `grep` the results were printed on individual lines and in color, but when I save the results to a variable and then print the variable out, the line breaks and colors are gone.

---

Is there any way to do what I'm asking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the option `--color=always`:

```
data=$(egrep -i --color=always "$search" file.data)
```

By default, `grep` does not produce color unless the output is going directly to a terminal.  This is normally a good thing.  The option `--color=always` overrides that.

For occasions when you don't want color, use `--color=never`.